# Reusing data between ViewModels in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, breeze

I have an array of **items** populated by an AJAX call in a knockout ViewModel, which displays a few fields of data for each item on a web page.

Now I need to enable the user to click on one item populating a side bar with data which was received from the previous AJAX request (a few fields plus a lot more).

I suppose typically one would take an **id** and do an **item**  specific AJAX request,  routing it through Sammy.js, but we don't need to.

I'm new to knockout; best policy I imagine is to have a ViewModel for the various divs to display the data, but how to get the ViewModels to pass data between themselves? Is this taboo?

- Making reference to the other window via the window object?
- Using the **with:** keyword? It keeps cropping up, but I can't see how to apply that in this context.
- Perhaps going via Sammy.js, and caching the data in **Amplify**?

This is an example of drill-down functionality, and I've read a number of StackOverflow Q&A about this but couldn't find up something I can use. I've got up to this stage by following John Papa's PluralSight tutorial.

Comment: There are a couple ways. You could use one ViewModel that holds the others, that handles interaction, or you could use pub/sub (or both). What specifically are you trying to communicate?

Comment: If you are interested in decoupled communication between separate view models, then you might be interested in this plugin: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox

Comment: @Tyrsius I have a click event which passes the parent object, that is the **item**, to the click function, I then want to convey this object to a much larger panel to display its finer details.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer thanks for the link. I had an idea that this would be a fairly simple task, isn't something like pub/sub overkill? Or is it just a case that it is actually quite simple to do?

Comment: @GeoffHogg It is really up to you. Two view models can simply contain references to each other, if you are comfortable with it. You can use a single observable in both (reference from one to the other).  It just depends on the complexity of the project and whether keeping your modules decoupled is important in your context. The postbox lib makes it really easy to keep it decoupled.

Comment: @GeoffHogg In the case of a click event, the binding could pass to an owning ViewModel via the relative bindings `$parent` or `$root`. This is where the Container viewmodel would come in handy, and may be simpler to implement. It gets crufty though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to go with a pub/sub model either with Amplify's messaging or the library the @RPNiemeyer mentions above. Both are excellent.

However it sounds like you just want to grab the data from the server, then use that data in multiple view models. Perhaps even sharing some of that data in multiple view models. The datacontext concept in my SPA tutorial allows you to host data in the datacontext and reference it from other view models.

You could also use a library like Breeze to help do this (Breeze would replace the datacontext in my SPA ... and be better at it as I will show in an upcoming course).

These are just a few options

Comment: Thanks, what is the ETA of your upcoming course?
What will it be about?

Comment: I've a few courses in the works. One is a SPA Fundamentals course that focuses on getting started with a SPA from scratch. Another involves adding some more advanced features to a SPA such as signalR. The intro course will be in early 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to checkout the "[Share an EntityManager](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/share-entitymanager)" post under "Cool Breezes" in the breeze documentation.

The sharing a single EntityManager is probably all you need. But if you think you need more than one, read "[Multiple managers](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/multiple-managers)".

Answer (score 1):

IMO The easiest way to do it is to simply pass "params" with an observable containing data to your sidebar component.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#passing-observable-expressions

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in comments, the good choice would be to use [**knockout-postbox**](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox)

> *knockout-postbox is a Knockout.js plugin designed to use Knockout's basic pub/sub capabilities to facilitate decoupled communication between separate view models / components.*

This allows you to set up simple topic-based communication like:

```
var ViewModelOne = function() {
  this.isEditable = ko.observable();  
};

var ViewModelTwo = function() {
  this.editable = ko.observable(false);  
};

var one = new ViewModelOne();
var two = new ViewModelTwo();

var editableTopic = "myEditableTopic";
one.isEditable.subscribeTo(editableTopic);
two.editable.publishOn(editableTopic)
```